# Connecting a stepper motor to Arduino using BNC cable

Tags: arduino-uno, robotics

I brought a bipolar stepper motor recently. I want to connect it to an Arduino. What i want doing is, i connected a 4 pin-BNC connector to the arduino and the other end to a DC power source. What i want to know is how to identify the positive and negative terminals of the stepper motor so that i can connect it to the output pins of the DC power source?

Answer (score 0):

Stepper motors don't have positive and negative terminals.  And you cannot connect one directly to an Arduino.  You need a stepper motor driver to provide the proper current and polarity for each stepper motor winding.  Google "bipolar stepper wiring" to see examples.

You can identify the *windings* with an ohmmeter and a diagram.  But don't connect an Arduino directly to a stepper without a separate driver or properly-sized Arduino shield designed for driving steppers.